# VPN running in vmware vm, is there any way to get the host to share that tunnel?

Tags: vmware-fusion, vpn

I'm running WinXP in VMWare Fusion hosted by MAC OS X 10.5.  There's no mac client for the vpn I need to use so I'm going through windows.  The vpn runs fine in the vm.  Is there a way I can get my host mac connection to piggyback off this vpn so I can access the network through the mac?

I can provide more info, so let me know what would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to setup Internet Connection Sharing within Windows on the VPN interface, then yes you could probably make it work.  You would probably have setup some routes on the Mac side.  The VM would almost certainly need to be setup with bridging.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? Single file access? I honestly know nothing about MAC OS, but found this thread that has a lot of info about VPN stuff on the mac side.

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2367343&tstart=0

Comment: I want full access through the vpn tunnel from the host machine.  I want to be able to ssh to other machines on the network, mount drives, access internal sites.  I've gotten answers from other sources that say this is probably not possible though.